# Disabling hangout calls for phone

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, google-hangouts

Is it possible to only disable voice/video calls in hangouts but leave messaging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope you cannot only selectively disable video calls. The least you can do is disable incoming invites from the app settings.

Comment: Yep, that's what I actually have done already, thanks